# Definition of height of an ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $I$ be an ideal of a commutative ring $A$.
Usually the height is defined as 
$$\operatorname{ht}(I) = \min_{\mathfrak p \supseteq I} \operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak p), $$ where $\mathfrak p$ runs over the prime ideals of $A$.

But we could define also:
$$h_1(I) = \sup \{ n \geq 0 : \exists\, \mathfrak p_0 \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq \mathfrak p_n \subset I, \mathfrak p_i \text{ prime} \}$$

1. I think that $h_1(I) = \sup_{\mathfrak p \subset I} \mathrm{ht}(\mathfrak p) =: h_2(I)$, am I right?
2. Is there an example where $\operatorname{ht}(I) \neq h_1(I)$ ? I don't really see why we made this definition of $\operatorname{ht}(I)$. Even geometrically, I don't really have an example where $\operatorname{codim}(Y)$ is not the same as the analogue of $h_1(I)$ for $Y=V(I)$.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you are right that $h_1(I)=h_2(I)$. I have provided your requested counter-example and the geometric justification for the standard definition of height of an ideal in my answer below.

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg, I thank you very much for your comment, as well as your pleasant answer.

Comment: You are welcome, Alphonse, and yours is a very sensible and natural question, which should be addressed in introductory books.

Comment: I understand the definition of $ht_1$, but the definition of $ht$ seems a bit circular to me. Is there a second, secret, definition for $ht(I)$ in case $I$ is prime?

Comment: @Vincent : see https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Height_of_an_ideal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the polynomial ring $A=k[X]$ over the field $k$ consider the ideal $I=\langle X^2\rangle$.
The  only prime ideal of $A$ containing $I$ is $\mathfrak  p=\langle X\rangle$, so that $ht(I)= ht(\mathfrak  p)=1$.
This is pleasant geometrically since $V(I)\subset \operatorname {Spec }k[X]=\mathbb A^1_k$ is the double point at the origin, whose codimension can reasonably only be thought of as $1$.
However your suggested height would be $h_1(I)=0$ since the only prime $\mathfrak p\subset I$ is $\mathfrak p=\langle0\rangle$ .
This would lead to the attribution of codimension $0$ to our double point $V(I)\subset \mathbb A^1_k$, a not so felicitous choice.